# Slow network performance on wifi access point connected through powerline ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point, powerline-networking

I have a home network with a router (dd-wrt firmware) connected to the internet that is also connected over a 200 Mbps powerline ethernet connection to another router (different make, also dd-wrt firmware). I disabled dhcp on the other router, which I'm using as an access point, so that all devices are on the same subnet.

When I connect over wifi to the router that's directly connected to the internet, I get 20 Mbps down and 6 up, which is around what I pay for. When I connect to the access point, I get < 1 megabit down and around 5 Mbps up. If I directly connect to the powerline ethernet, I get 20 down and 6 up. However, if I connect directly to one of the lan ports on the access point I get similar speeds to connecting directly to the powerline.

From here, it seems that either the broadcasted signal from the access point is faulty, or some underlying problem with dd-wrt on the access point is causing the problem. When I connect wirelessly to it, my laptop is 2 feet from the access point (and the laptop reports 100% connection). I have tried having the access point have a different SSID, as well as the same SSID. I followed [this guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) for the access point setup. I have tried both the "long" and "short" version but neither seemed to change much.

Has anyone else ran into similar issues with access points?

Main router: Asus RT-N10+ DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) std

Access point: Linksys E1200 v2 DD-WRT v24-sp2 (05/27/13) mini

Comment: This may not be your problem, but 2 feet is too close for Wi-Fi. At that range, the signal can be so strong that the receiver is overloaded and distorts it (think of having someone shouting directly into your ear). For best results, you want to keep your RSSI below -40dBm, but above -60dBm. If your software doesn't show you RSSI in dBm, do your performance testing with the devices about 2m (~7′) away from each other.

Comment: @Spiff I also tried running the speed test on my laptop from the adjacent room. The laptop was about 3 feet away from the router with a wall between it. My laptop measures the signals in dB; I will try again in the suggested range.

Comment: The performance was the same ~7 feet away (around 47 dBm)

Comment: @Spiff If I put the routers on channels 6 and 11 @ 20Mhz band, respectively, with WMM on I get the same < 1 Mbps speed. Same if I put them both on the same channel (11). However, if I turn off WMM and put them on the same channel I get a good dl / upload speed. Do you know of a reason that WMM (or rather, using 802.11n / 802.11ac) would cause poor performance? I've updated my question with the router models & DD-WRT versions.

Comment: Wow, that's really surprising to me. It makes me wonder if one of the boxes just has a terribly broken WMM implementation or something, that's so much of a liability that it's better to switch it off and deal with the consequences.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was a goodwill router. Model doesn't look that old. I will look into replacing it to see if I can fix the problem.